# Odd behavior when converting columns of dataframe to factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert all the columns of a dataframe to factors. However, the conversion to factors make all my entries become `string` instead of `numeric`. See example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
df_factor <- apply(df, 2, factor)
```

This is what I get:

```
 #> df_factor
 #     a   b  
 #[1,] "1" "4"
 #[2,] "2" "5"
 #[3,] "3" "6"
```

Would you have an idea as to where the problem is coming from?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply(df, 2, factor)` changes your dataframe to a matrix. Use this instead:

```
df_factor <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, factor))
```

Comment: It works great, thanks. However, when I try to `cbind` this factor dataframe with a normal vector, I get something weird again..

Comment: `cbind` or `rbind`? Factors cause trouble for `rbind` usually. What is the problem?

Comment: Or just `df[] <- lapply(df, factor)`

Comment: @Mariam, is it that you want the factor levels to be the same in each column, perhaps? If so, maybe something like `df[] <- lapply(df, factor, unlist(df))`, but you should really update your question to show what exactly you're trying to do in the long run, or post a follow-up question as the question the way you have asked it has been appropriately answered.

Answer (score 0):

A `plyr` alternative:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- colwise(factor)(df)
```